# MVC architecture implementation

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Originally I had the view holding commands for buttons, these buttons calculated this and output text onto JTextAreas after being pushed. What is produced is dependent on the value returned.

I am concerned I am not following standard MVC architecture by setting text like below inside my controller.

At the moment I changed my button commands into my controller as so

```
private class ReadActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent l) {
    /* there is other code in here, which results in setting text its not  
       just a set text button*/
    /*interactions with model etc etc, outcome true? setText JTextArea like below*/
              view.variable.setText("hi there");
    }
}
```

Should I be setting text for the view inside the controller or is this breaking standard MVC architecture?

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Set your view data in the controller, if you want it to mirror the model then *get your data from the model*, and *then* set the view data using the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC, you should not update the view from the controller. The controller is meant for event handling and altering the model according to these events. The model should then update its observers, ie. the view.

You can read up on the Observer design pattern here: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2011/12/observer-design-pattern-java-example.html

There is a code example provided on that website as well.

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, the model is a **layer**.

The model *layer* comprises of multiple objects: domain objects, services and mappers. You can read more in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000) (although in PHP, the concepts still hold substance).

That being said, your controller handles the input from the user, sends this to the relevant *object* within the model *layer*, which then returns this data to the controller - and then your controller sends this to the view instance which handles the logic for displaying this to the user.

The observer pattern is really interesting and Koen's link above is a good one. I saved this snippet a while back from somewhere on SO:

> Have state-setting operations on Subject call Notify after they change the 
>   subject's state. The advantage of this approach is that clients don't have 
>   to remember to call Notify on the subject. The disadvantage is that several
>   consecutive operations will cause several consecutive updates, which may be
>   inefficient.
>
> Make clients responsible for calling Notify at the right time. The advantage 
>   here is that the client can wait to trigger the update until after a series 
>   of state changes has been made, thereby avoiding needless intermediate updates.
>   The disadvantage is that clients have an added responsibility to trigger the 
>   update. That makes errors more likely, since clients might forget to call Notify.

This old but still valid example of the observer pattern may still be useful: http://javanook.tripod.com/patterns/observer.html